# Correlated subquery performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I've found what seems to be a bottleneck query in one of my stored procedures. @Results is table variable with ~17K rows. It includes a TimeStamp (DateTime) column and a Value (decimal) column.

The correlated subquery approach was the first thing I could think of to accomplish this task, but the performance is **very poor**. I can't think of a better way to structure this query other than "computing" the WHERE clause using a correlated subquery against the same table. Any advice on how this can be written better...

I'm basically trying to select the highest value from a subset of the full results. Now, a result record is included in the subset by counting all of the values that are less than or equal to that value, multiplying it by 100, dividing it by @Count, and seeing if it's greater than some percent.

Here's the query:

```
SELECT TOP 1 @Result = Results.Value
FROM @Results Results
WHERE (100.0 * (SELECT COUNT(1) 
                FROM @Results Results2
                WHERE Results2.Value <= Results.Value) / @Count) >= @Percent
ORDER BY Results.Value ASC
```

Any advice or assistance would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: No, there's not an index on Results.Value. Results is a table variable. Can you add an index to a table variable?

Comment: Looks like you can't unless you declare a PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE constraint when you first create it: http://sqlserverplanet.com/sql/create-index-on-table-variable - if that's not an option, perhaps you should store `@Results` in a `#tempResults` table first, which you *can* index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would help to have a better idea what is trying to be achieved, expressed in user-domain terms rather than SQL.

Also, the entire scope and structure of the data being queried isn't given, but probably includes relationships that are involved in the determination of performance.

For one thing, there's this Results table variable, which has its own derivation. This technique can be risky because it builds in an implicit temp table which is often a deoptimizer. It's like you're trying to dictate strategy to the query optimizer.

It appears that you just want one maximum value from an aggregate query, which should be optimizable. Actually, optimizing shouldn't even be an issue with only 17K records.

Can you restate this in the form:

```
SELECT MAX(Value)
FROM some-aggregate-query
GROUP BY fields
HAVING COUNT(something)/COUNT(1) * 100 > @percent
```

Hint: in my experience you're usually headed in the wrong direction when you start decomposing SQL (which is exactly the opposite of the best policy for procedural code.)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm particularly interested in your comment about the table variable being a "deoptimizer". Do you care to elaborate? Are table variables generally bad? I actually switched out the above query to use a temp table, marked TimeStamp as the PK, created an index on Value, and the execution time dropped to under a third of what is was before. What gives?

Answer (score 0):

Hm what about this: First, select the total count of rows into a variable. Next, you select the row which is at index (@Percent / 100.0 * countOfRowsTotal), ordering by Value.

That will scan the table 1 to 2 times.